# Remove "creases"/shadows between objects right next to each other

Tags: three.js

I'm getting these these weird lines/shadows along the gaps between two objects placed with their faces exactly touching. It seems like they are trying to cast shadows on each other even though there's no space between them.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the mesh for each column:

```
const col = new Mesh(
    new BoxGeometry(colSize, 1, colSize),
    new MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xee4423 })
);
col.castShadow = true;
col.receiveShadow = true;
```

Other lighting settings:

```
this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(-d * aspect, d * aspect, d, -d, .3, 1000);
this.camera.position.set(60, 60, 60);
this.camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

this.ambientLight = new AmbientLight(0xffffff, .35);

this.light = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.75);
this.light.shadow.bias = 0.0001;
this.light.castShadow = true;
this.light.shadow.mapSize.width = 4096;
this.light.shadow.mapSize.height = 4096;
this.light.shadow.camera.near = .1;
this.light.shadow.camera.far = 500;
this.light.shadow.camera.top = 500;
this.light.shadow.camera.right = 500;
this.light.shadow.camera.bottom = -500;
this.light.shadow.camera.left = -500;

this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
this.renderer.shadowMap.type = PCFSoftShadowMap;
this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
```

Comment: You might notice there are also light lines within your shadows where one shape meets another. I'd continue to fiddle with the `bais` and `mapSize`. Meanwhile, could you set up a simple example that shows the same effect as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: @TheJim01 It's in TypeScript actually so it may take some time to make a proper demo of exactly this, but I'll try and give you something with the same lighting settings. Changing the `bias` to anything else seems to break the lighting completely. And my `mapSize` is at `4096` already, any higher and I get a big performance degradation.

Comment: @TheJim01 In the meantime, I've edited my question with ALL of my camera, lighting, and renderer settings.

Comment: You might also try changing the `.top .right .bottom. left` values to something smaller so the shadow resolution isn't spread too thin. If your camera is at `x: 60`, I'm guessing your scene doesn't warrant a shadow camera that spans from -500 to +500 units.

Comment: @Marquizzo Okay, that seems to help. After some trial and error I found the best setting for the shadow camera size was `50` for the `top right bottom left`. But I see the lines faintly on two or three of the columns still. And now with the shadow map is so small the shadows are too hard-edged, but if I reduce the shadow `mapSize` then the lines come back. Are there any other settings I could try?

Comment: You ever find out a solution?